# I am not getting why BasicCard rich response is not showing using webhook fulfilment in the dialogflow test simulator

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

This problem is arising when using events. Say, after a particular event 'A' occurs, intent 'X' is called. 'X' has fulfillment webhook which tries to render a SimpleResponse response and a BasicCard response. But, in the simulator, only the SimpleResponse can be seen and not the BasicCard. There are no errors reported in the simulator also. Below is the JSON response:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Sample Text1"
            }
          },
          {
            "basicCard": {
              "title": "Sample Text2 ",
              "formattedText": " Sample Text3",
              "image": {
                "url": "Sample working URL1"
              },
              "buttons": [
                {
                  "title": "Sample Text4",
                  "openUrlAction": {
                    "url": "Sample working URL2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now what is surprising, the same JSON response renders both SimpleResponse as well as BasicCard response when another intent 'Y' is called by one of its utterance. 'Y' is also linked to a webhook fulfillment. 
Any reason why?

Comment: The JSON you have pasted there isn't valid JSON, so something seems fishy somewhere. How are you generating the response, using a library, through the Dialogflow responses, or making the JSON yourself? How are you testing it, using the Dialogflow simulator or the Actions on Google simulator? Can you update your question to answer some of these issues, and show screen shots of the Intents in question and the responses? If you're using the Actions simulator, can you include the contents of the "Response" tab?

Comment: Corrected the JSON. I am generating responses taking the help of fulfillment webhook. Testing it on Actions on Google simulator. Now, I tested it on phone and it is working fine. But not on the simulator.

Comment: Can you update your question with the text of the "Response" tab and a screen shot that includes the "Display" tab to illustrate?